# Initialize rating plugin using angularjs variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-plugins, rating

I am using this rating plugin (http://metroui.org.ua/rating.html) in angularjs to show rating in star. I tried to initialize the current rating when page loads.

```
data-score="3"
```

is working but this

`data-score="{{userreviewRatings.rating}}"`
is not working

```
        <div id="rating-stars" class="large fg-white rating active" style="height: auto;" data-score="{{userreviewRatings.rating}}">
        </div>
        <form id="rating-form">
        <input type="text" id="website-rating" ng-click="submitrating()" name="rating">                
        </form>
        <script>

                    $(function(){
                        $("#rating-stars").rating({
                            static: false,
                            stars: 5,
                            showHint: true,
                            showScore: false,
                            click: function(value, rating){
                                rating.rate(value);
                                $('#website-rating').val(value);
                                $('#website-rating').trigger('click');
                            }
                        });
                    });

        </script>
```

can someone please tell me how can i give rating using angular variable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't it's good to use both angular and jquery. they are very different in thought.
if you really want to use both of them. you should use `$scope.$digest()`after 
`$scope.userreviewRatings.rating`has changed.
or use 
```

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#rating-stars").rating({
            static: false,
            stars: 5,
            showHint: true,
            showScore: false,
            click: function (value, rating) {
                rating.rate(value);
                $('#website-rating').val(value);
                $('#website-rating').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    });
})
```

```